# Make images scroll in from the sides when scrolling down a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

Would there be a reliable way to move an image from offscreen to the left of the screen when a user scrolls down to that part of the page?

I made it so that the picture fades in and is offscreen at first but how do I give the image another animation so that it slides in depending on how far you scrolled down?

This is what I have so far.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var scrollVal = window.scrollY;
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = scrollVal;
  document.title = scrollVal;
})
```

```css
.Img1 {
  animation: fadeIn 5s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.side {
  animation: scrollIn 5s;
  float: right !important;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: -90% !important;
}

@keyframes scrollIn {
  0% {
    margin-right: -90% !important;
  }
  100% {
    margin-right: 0% !important;
  }
}

.Img1 {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test Test Test Test </h1>
<h3>Test Test Test Test Test </h3>
<p>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test </p>
<div class="Img1">
  <img src="https://iili.io/J9HycQe.md.png" alt="J9HycQe.md.png" class="side">
</div>
<p id="test">___</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) optimally handles your scenario versus a `scroll` event listener.

> The Intersection Observer API provides a way to asynchronously observe changes in the intersection of a target element with an ancestor element or with a top-level document's viewport.

A `scroll` event listener runs on the main thread that "can cause performance problems" in the browser.

> The Intersection Observer API lets code register a callback function that is executed whenever a particular element enters or exits an intersection with another element (or the viewport) ... sites no longer need to do anything on the main thread to watch for this kind of element intersection, and the browser is free to optimize the management of intersections as it sees fit.

The first use case (Lazy loading images) listed in this [css-tricks.com article](https://css-tricks.com/a-few-functional-uses-for-intersection-observer-to-know-when-an-element-is-in-view/) is similar to your scenario. I've adapted it to your code with the following changes:

- The class `Img1` in your code was changed to `img-container`.
- The `scrollIn` animation was removed from the `side` CSS rule to a separate rule `animate-into-view`. The `animate-into-view` rule is applied to the `img` element when the `.img-container` parent element intersects with the viewport.
- `!important` was removed from the `margin-rule` property setting so that the property settings in the `@keyframes scrollIn` animation could be applied.

```js
let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.querySelector("img").classList.add("animate-into-view");
      observer.unobserve(entry.target);
    }
  });
}, {
  rootMargin: "0px 0px -90% 0px"
});

document.querySelectorAll('.img-container').forEach(el => {
  observer.observe(el)
});
```

```css
.img-container {
  animation: fadeIn 5s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.side {
  float: right !important;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: -90%;
}

.animate-into-view {
  animation: scrollIn 5s 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes scrollIn {
  0% {
    margin-right: -90%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-right: 0%;
  }
}

.img-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test Test Test Test </h1>
<h3>Test Test Test Test Test </h3>
<p>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test </p>
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://iili.io/J9HycQe.md.png" alt="J9HycQe.md.png" class="side">
</div>
<h1>Test Test Test Test </h1>
<h3>Test Test Test Test Test </h3>
<p>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test </p>
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://iili.io/J9HycQe.md.png" alt="J9HycQe.md.png" class="side">
</div>
<h1>Test Test Test Test </h1>
<h3>Test Test Test Test Test </h3>
<p>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test </p>
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://iili.io/J9HycQe.md.png" alt="J9HycQe.md.png" class="side">
</div>
```

Update: This [SO post answered on Sept 24th, 2023](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77167016) shows a similar question/scenario and solution using the Intersection Observer API.