# IntersectionObserver and transform: translate unpredictable behaviour

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I have the following code, which I'm trying to implement `IntersectionObserver` to show `div`'s once they're intersecting with the `root viewport` by translating the divs from `400%` to `0`. However it produces weird and irrational behavior. With the same configuration, I just replaced the `transform: translateX` with the `opacity`, and the `IntersectionObserver` worked smoothly as expected.

```js
const allDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".content");

// Observer Options
const obsOptions = {
  root: null,
  threshold: 1,
};

// Observer Callback
const obsCallback = function (entries, observer) {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    if (entry.isIntersecting && entry.intersectionRatio >= 1) {
      entry.target.classList.add("show");
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.remove("show");
    }
  }

};

// Creating Observer
const theObserver = new IntersectionObserver(obsCallback, obsOptions);


allDivs.forEach((div) => {
  theObserver.observe(div);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
  /* height: 150vh; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

div.container {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

div.container .content {
  background-color: chocolate;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateX(400%);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
}

div.container .content.show {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Scroll Animation</title>
</head>
<body>
    
  
        <h1>Scroll to see animation</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">Content</div>
            <div class="content">Content</div>
            <div class="content">Content</div>
            <div class="content">Content</div>
            <div class="content">4th - Content</div>
            <div class="content">Content</div>
            <div class="content">Content</div>
            <div class="content">Content</div>
            <div class="content">Content</div>
            <div class="content">Content</div>
            <div class="content">4th - Content</div>
           </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Thus, do the IntersectionObserver and transform don't work together or there is something I'm missing? Thanks for your cooperation

Answer (score 2):

This part causes the `show` class to be constantly added and removed so the animation doesn't have time to be shown.

```
if (entry.isIntersecting && entry.intersectionRatio >= 1) {
    entry.target.classList.add("show");
} else {
    entry.target.classList.remove("show");
}
```

So i changed it to be only added and not to be removed after:

```
if (entry.isIntersecting && entry.intersectionRatio >= 1) {
    entry.target.classList.add("show");
}
```

Here is the fully working example:

```js
const allDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".content");

// Observer Options
const obsOptions = {
  root: null,
  threshold: 1,
};


// Observer Callback
const obsCallback = function (entries, observer) {
  for (const entry of entries) {   
    if (entry.isIntersecting && entry.intersectionRatio >= 1) {
      entry.target.classList.add("show");
    }
  }
};

// Creating Observer
const theObserver = new IntersectionObserver(obsCallback, obsOptions);


allDivs.forEach((div) => {
  theObserver.observe(div);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
  /* height: 150vh; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  background-color: chocolate;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
}

.show {
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: anim;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    transform: translateX(400%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Scroll Animation</title>
</head>
<body>
    
  
        <h1>Scroll to see animation</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="a"></div>
            <div class="content">Content</div>
            <div class="content">Content</div>
            <div class="content">Content</div>
            <div class="content">Content</div>
            <div class="content">4th - Content</div>
            <div class="content">Content</div>
            <div class="content">Content</div>
            <div class="content">Content</div>
            <div class="content">Content</div>
            <div class="content">Content</div>
            <div class="content">4th - Content</div>
           </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```